# Ionic V3 Request randomly fail in Chrome Browser and Emulator

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, ionic3, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-httpclient

I have a weird problem with Http-Requests randomly failing with an Ionic(V3) App using the Http-Client from Angular (7.1.1). 
The Backend is an ASP.NET Core Web API with CORS configured to allow any Headers, Methods and Origins.

To figure out the problem I switched from Emulator to Browser. After resolving some CORS Issues I noticed that the problem with failing requests only exists in Chrome (FF and Edge are working fine).
The HTTP Requests fail with: "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE", after clicking back and forth the network tab looks like this:

[image]

I can't explain why some Requests don't have the Preflight request, but those requests seem to always succeed (they also have den header "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" which should alway trigger the Options-Preflight, if I am correct?)

Also every requests, even the failing ones, reach the backend and resolve successfully on the backend.

The error on the client in the console:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "Unknown Error",
    "url": null,
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",
    "error": {
        "isTrusted": true
    }
}
```

Reading the Ionic forums this leads to a CORS problem. Perhaps I overlooked something, so here is my CORS-Configuration from the Backend:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("*")
                       .WithMethods("*")
                       .WithHeaders("*");
            });
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Any hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Web API project is on aspnet core 2.2 then it could be related to this issue:
[Response that returns 204 fails with HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED/INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE in ANCM In-process](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4398)

There is three options:

- Downgrade to aspnetcore 2.1
- Upgrade to 2.2.1 / 3.0.0 preview
- Use the work around mentioned on the issue:

Add the following as the first lines of your StartUp.cs Configure method.

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
  await next();
  if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
  {
    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
  }
});
```

Also about the preflight not firing everytime, the browser cache includes the results of preflight OPTIONS calls so instead of having to fire a preflight on every request, it only fires once the cache has expired.

Lastly: configuring CORS with an accept of any origin can be unsafe, see:[CORS security: reflecting any origin header value when configured to * is dangerous](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3106)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't expect an issue with IIS/.NetCore.